# Count occurrences within range

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have a dataset which like:

```
ID Amt   TYPE
1  1000  A
2  200   NA
3  1100  S
```

I need to count the occurrences of each type within a specific range for each type:

```
Range     A_Count NA_Count S_Count
0-1000    1       1        0
1001-2000 0       0        1
```

I am tyring to get this so that I can draw a plot using this dataframe, with range as the x-axis and the counts as y-axis. How do I achieve this?

Comment: I changed your example output to have non overlapping ranges, such that the lines don't change.

Please note however, that your first line goes from 0 to 1000 (1001 different values)
whereas the second line goes from 1001 to 2000 (1000 different values)

In order to have non overlapping uniform rows I'd do following, but was'nt sure whether this is acceptable

0-999,  1000-1999, 2000-2999,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Tabulating

First [**`cut()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) the amounts into ranges and then [**`crosstab()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) vs type:

```py
df['Range'] = pd.cut(df.Amt, bins=[0, 1000, 2000])
tab = pd.crosstab(df.Range, df.TYPE).add_suffix('_Count')

# TYPE          A_Count  NA_Count  S_Count
# Range                                   
# (0, 1000]           1         1        0
# (1000, 2000]        0         0        1
```

- Note that if `NA` here means `NaN`, then [**`replace()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) them as strings when tabulating:

  ```py
  tab = pd.crosstab(df.Range, df.TYPE.replace(np.nan, 'NA')).add_suffix('_Count')
  ```
- By default, the tabulation will drop empty bins. If you want  to keep all bins, use `dropna=False`:

  ```py
  tab = pd.crosstab(df.Range, df.TYPE, dropna=False).add_suffix('_Count')
  ```

---

#### Plotting

Plot the cross table either with [**`DataFrame.plot.bar()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```py
tab.plot.bar()
```

Or [**`seaborn.barplot()`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html):

```py
sns.barplot(
    data=tab.reset_index().melt('Range', value_name='Count'),
    x='Range',
    y='Count',
    hue='TYPE',
)
```

[image: crosstab figure]

Comment: How do I split it into equal sized bins? Considering my values are pretty large

Comment: @tdy: `pd.crosstab` has a `dropna` option set to True by default. You can set it to False to handle NaNs as any other value (see my answer for a similar option in `value_counts`.

Comment: @sinha-shaurya if you set `bins` to an integer like `bins=5`, it will automatically create 5 equal-sized bins. do you mean something like that?

Comment: @sinha-shaurya: the `bins` parameter in `pd.cut` can take an int as value to define the number of groups: `pd.cut(df.Amt, bins=2)`. They will have an equal widths.

Comment: Yes I tried that. I set my number of bins to 10 . Still when I see the dataframe tab, it has only 2 rows i,e only 2 bins

Comment: @sinha-shaurya ahh ok, then in this case you do want `dropna=False`. i think the issue is that your data only falls into 2 of the 10 bins, so by default the crosstab only shows those 2 bins. `dropna=False` will force `crosstab` to keep all the bins (answer updated)

Comment: @tdy: my bad, the `dropna` option in `crosstab` is different that that in `value_counts` *Do not include columns whose entries are all NaN.*, so it seems expected that counting NaNs is not possible

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) and [pandas.DataFrame.unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)

```
df['group'] =  pd.cut(df.Amt, [0,1000,1100])
(df.groupby('group')
   ['TYPE'].value_counts(dropna=False)
   .unstack(-1)
   .fillna(0)
   .add_suffix('_count')
)
```

output:

```
TYPE          nan_count  A_count  S_count
group                                    
(0, 1000]           1.0      1.0      0.0
(1000, 1100]        0.0      0.0      1.0
```